# How to Update existing record and insert new record in SQL table ? SQL

Tags: c#, gridview, sql-server-2012

I have a table.I want to update the table.Actually I have a gridview which retrieve values from SQL table.When page load then gridview load the values .I want that when i insert new values in gridview then in SQL Table existing values update and also new values insert in the same table using SINGLE query.How can i do this?Just tell me SQL query which works in C#,ASP.NET 
Thanks

```
public void insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string user = Session["name"].ToString();
 SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HAMEED_KHAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_compiler;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT User_ID from tbl_user WHERE User_Name='" + user + "'", cnn);
cnn.Open();
string id = cmd3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
int ID = Int32.Parse(id);
Session["ID"] = ID;
string d = Session["value"].ToString();
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Database_id FROM Create_db WHERE Database_Name='" + d + "'", cnn);
Response.Write("<script>Var Z=Prompt('Enter Table Name');</script>");
string dbid = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
cnn.Close();
int D_ID = Int32.Parse(dbid);
string str = "";
string type = "";
for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
{
 str = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
 type = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
 string Name = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
 string Type = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
 string size = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text.ToString();
 CheckBox allow = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
 CheckBox primary = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
 string UserID = Session["ID"].ToString();
 int UID = Int32.Parse(UserID);
 string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
 string A = (allow.Checked == true ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL");
 string P = (primary.Checked == true ? "PRIMARY KEY" : "");
 string Table = Session["TBL_NAME"].ToString();
 string queryy ="USE db_compiler UPDATE tbl_field SET Column_Name='" + Name + "', Data_Type='" + Type + "',Size='" + size + "',Database_id='" + D_ID + "',Allow_Null_='" + (allow.Checked == true ? "true" : "false") + "',Primary_Key_='" + (primary.Checked == true ? "true" : "false") + "',User_id='" + UID + "',Date='" + date + "' WHERE Table_Name='" + Table + "' IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 insert into tbl_field (Table_Name,Column_Name,Data_Type,Size,Database_id,Allow_Null_,Primary_Key_,User_id,Date) VALUES('" + Table + "','" + Name + "','" + Type + "','" + size + "','" + D_ID + "','" + (allow.Checked == true ? "true" : "false") + "','" + (primary.Checked == true ? "true" : "false") + "','" + UID + "','" + date + "')";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryy, cnn);
  SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 cnn.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  cnn.Close();
}
}
```

[gridview-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13f8O.png)
Table name is 'employee' first i have 3 rows in gridview 'Name','id','address' when i insert new row 'ph' and click on 'update tabe' then i update all rows with 'ph'

[db image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyNNj.png)

Comment: There are plenty of resource available on web for what you are asking! Search on the web.

Comment: I search on web.I found the UPDATE query,But I want that update and new record insert in the same table at same time..

Answer (score 1):

```
    foreach (GridViewRow g1 in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
                    com = new SqlCommand("insert into student(sid,sname,smarks,saddress) values ('" + g1.Cells[0].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[1].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[2].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[3].Text + "')", con);
                    con.Open();
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();

                }
```

If you insert new record at last row of gridview then get the index of last wow using:

```
Int32 index = dataGridveiw1.Rows.Count - 1;
```

For More You can refer this Article : [Insert Data in Database Using GridView Control](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b926a6/insert-data-in-database-using-gridview-control/)

**EDIT:**

You can use this approach to insert and update data with single query:

```
  INSERT INTO student(sid, sname, smarks) VALUES('" + g1.Cells[0].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[1].Text + "','" + g1.Cells[2].Text + "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sname="g1.Cells[1].Text", smarks="g1.Cells[2].Text";
```

Comment: I'm asking for UPDATE existing record and insert new record in the same table at same time using one query.I'm not asking for insert query?Understand my question.

Comment: Kindly check my updated question.I try your query but error comes .Here is error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'."

Comment: update student set sname='" + g1.Cells[0].Text + "' where id=yourid
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
   insert into student (sname) values('" + g1.Cells[0].Text + "');  Try this. And let me know the result.

Comment: kindly check my updated question.I try your sql command but output is not corrected